# Create Site Column Programmatically In SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How to create site column of Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
SPList _list = web.Lists["ListName"];
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.LinkField linkfds = _list.Fields.CreateNewField("Link", "Test") as Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.LinkField;
_list.Fields.Add(linkfds);
_list.Update();
```

Note - you should add reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll`